# Does $A^{p^2}=I$ lead to $(A-I)^{p^2}=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields

Suppose that $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with entries in a finite field $F_p$ where $p$ is prime, $1\leq n \leq p$. An exercise answer told me that $$A^{p^2}=I\Rightarrow (A-I)^{p^2}=0.$$

I don't know why this holds. I tried to expand the equation as
$$
0=A^{p^2}-I^{p^2}=\left( A-I \right) \left( A^{p^2-1}+A^{p^2-2}+\cdots +A+I \right),
$$
but still have no idea what info is given. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance！

Comment: Expand $(A-I)^{p^2}$ instead, using the binomial theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#Prime_characteristic

Comment: The binomial theorem holds for any pair of commuting elements in a ring.

Comment: @player3236@PQH@runway44 Binomial theorem actually works: every coefficient (except the first and the last terms) is a multiple of $p^2$, i.e., $\bar{0} in F_p$! Thank you all!

Comment: $\binom{9}{3}=84$ is not multiple of $9$. But it is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @lhf You are right, I should have used $p$ instead of $p^2$.

Answer (score 3):

The binomial coefficients $\binom{p}{k}$ are all multiples of $p$ for $0 <k < p$. Therefore
$$
(A-I)^{p^2}=((A-I)^p)^p=(A^p-I^p)^p=A^{p^2}-I=0
$$